# C# trim string returned from function

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to trim the end of a string of variable length returned from a function.

The function returns a string formatted like:
    PC Type + "\t\t" + MACAddress + "\t\t" + NumPC + "\t\t" + Date

eg:

> Server      00:11:22:33:44:55      124     06-12-13
>
> PC          AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF      16      01-01-12

I am attempting to remove the part of the string after the MAC address, I have tried using the below method but don't seem to be having much luck.

```
int index = Licences.LastIndexOf(":");
if (index > 0)
Licences = Licences.Substring(0, index + 2);
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: I'd say that's about as elegant as it will get. Are you saying it doesn't work?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Licences = Licences.Substring(0, index + 3);

Comment: No not working, I'm getting the entire string as output (also when I use index +3 as suggested by Matheus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) is six groups of two hexadecimal digits, separated by hyphens (-) or colons (:) you can use regex to match server name and MAC address:

```
string input = "Server 00:11:22:33:44:55 124 06-12-13";
var match = Regex.Match(input, ".+[0-9a-f]{2}([-:][0-9a-f]{2}){5}");
if (match.Success)    
   string result = match.Value; // "Server 00:11:22:33:44:55"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            String Licences = "Server 00:11:22:33:44:55 124 06-12-13";
            String [] names = Licences.Split(' ');
            Licences="";
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length - 2; i++)
                Licences += names[i] + " ";

            Licences=Licences.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like this:

```
var expression = @"(?<=:..)\s";
var targetString = "PC AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 16 01-01-12";
var splitString = Regex.Split(targetString, expression).last();
```

The expression will match

```
 \s:    any whitespace
 (?<=   that occurs directly after
 :..    a colon with any two characters after it.
```

Also you could change the `.`s to `[A-Fa-f0-9]` (twice) to make sure it really only matches hexadecimal digits.